# How do I evaluate this limit?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I'm trying to evaluate this limit:

$$\lim_{r\to 10}\int_0^r\sqrt\frac{{400-3x^2}}{400-4x^2}\ dx$$

at $x = 9.99999999999$, the value is $12.1105532$, so I feel like it is approaching some value around this. Does that mean there is a limit ? How do I evaluate that limit?

Comment: Here is a guide to MathJax! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You should use a different letter for the variable of integration.  $x$ is performing two different jobs here.

Comment: looks like a complete elliptic integral to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can see the limit results in the improper integral

$$L=\int_0^{10}\sqrt{\frac{400-3x^2}{400-4x^2}}~\mathrm dx$$

Now consider the substitution $x=10t$ to get

$$L=10\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{400-300t^2}{400-400t^2}}~\mathrm dt=10\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac34t^2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}~\mathrm dt=10E(\sqrt{3}/2)$$

Where $E(k)$ is a [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: Thank you so much! Quick question : Can I use the elliptic integral function on an integral as long as its in the form ((a-bx^2)/(c-dx^2))^0.5

Comment: @sidharthramanan In general, you will need the [incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) to solve those integrals, unless the bounds come out right, then you'll use the complete elliptic integral.

Answer (score 5):

This is a complete elliptic integral: in Maple's notation

$$ \int_0^{10} \sqrt{\frac{400-3x^2}{400-4x^2}}\; dx = 10 \; \text{EllipticE}(\sqrt{3}/2)$$

The approximate numerical value is $12.11056028$.